# c++ template of template

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include "boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp"
using namespace boost::numeric::ublas;
template <class matrixform,class input_T>
class Layer
{
private:
    matrixform <input_T>;
public:
};
```

I want to be able to do

```
int main ()
{
Layer<identity_matrix, double> mylayer;
}
```

BUT

> layer.hpp:18: error: ‘matrixform’ is
>   not a template layer.hpp:18: error:
>   declaration does not declare anything

Answer (score 3):

You would need to use a template template parameter:

```
template <template <class> class matrixform, class input_T>
class Layer { /* ... */ };
```

Note that in order to use a template template parameter, the template provided as an argument must have parameters that exactly match the list.  So, in this example here, only a template taking one type parameter can be used to instantiate `Layer`.

This is a problem, especially since a class template parameter can have a default argument.  The Boost `identity_matrix` class, for example, has two template parameters:  the type and the allocator to be used, so it could not be used to instantiate `Layer` (the allocator parameter has a default argument).

What you can do instead is take as a template parameter the instantiated template to use, and get the `input_T` from a typedef defined by that type.  For example:

```
template <typename MatrixT>
class Layer
{
    typedef typename MatrixT::value_type ValueT;
};
```

`MatrixT` here is what `matrixform<input_T>` is in your example, and `ValueT` is your `input_T`.

This can be instantiated as,

```
Layer<identity_matrix<double> > mylayer;
```

Comment: can you plz explain what's inside the class ?

Comment: @ismail:  What, exactly, do you not understand?  (And, why is it that typing "please" is so difficult?)

Comment: sry man ddn mean 2 mk u angry :) , p.s i replied before you edit :) so i didn't see your full answer

Answer (score 0):

```
template <class templatedmatrixform> 
class Layer 
{ 
private: 
    templatedmatrixform matrix; 
public: 
}; 

 template<typename T>
 class identity_matrix
 {
       typedef T input_T;
 };


int main () 
{ 
    Layer<identity_matrix<double> > mylayer; 
}
```

Comment: identity_matrix is already defined in boost , with bunch of others like triangular_matrix so ?

Comment: I didn't realize to was a pre-defined class.  The typedef is there just incase you need that type elsewhere in Layer.  Fortunately, the boost class defines it as `value_type`, so whereever you'd use `input_T` in your Layer class, you can use `templatedmatrixform::value_type`.